# Выбор инструмента для кэширования с поддержкой персистентности

Tags: java, кэширование, persistance

Всем доброго времени суток.

Так вышло, что для проекта мне необходимо найти инструмент для кэширования больших файлов (картинки, видео). Все закэшированные данные(key + value) должны располагаться в оперативной памяти. При этом должен быть какой-то файл на диске, содержащий весь кэш, чтобы при сбое данные сохранились. Он и должен подгружаться в оперативку.

Мной были **поверхностно** изучены HazelCast и Apache JCS. Но таких функции персистентности там не обнаружено.

Прошу вас подсказать, какими инструментами лучше воспользоваться в такой ситуации. Или, возможно, есть примеры самописной реализации.

Я относительно недавно в этой области, сразу прошу прощения если какие-то термины употреблены неверно.

Comment: а как вы будете инвалидировать кэш? очень похоже на XY проблему.

Comment: Не уверен, но посмотрите в сторону http://www.ehcache.org/, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehcache

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman что значит инвалидировать кэш?

Comment: если данные изменились, то необходимо обновить их в кеше. для этого кешированные данные надо сделать недействительными - этот процес называется инвалидацией кэша.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Замена изменившихся данных с помощью операции put, допустим

Comment: то что вы описываете - это не кэш. это просто БД. вы можете взять любую которая умеет держать все в памяти.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman так необходимость в создании кэша и возникла с целью разгрузки бд

Comment: просто вы описываете не кэш, а БД. кэш должен быть прозрачен для пользователя, то есть никаких прямых **put** в кэш быть не должно. если БД не справляется, то стоит рассмотреть другую БД или поменять настройки БД (сделать кластер, например)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлю к ответу @АлександрМартынцев

Можно сконфигурить через ehcache:

```
Configuration cacheManagerConfig = new Configuration()
    .diskStore(new DiskStoreConfiguration()
    .path("/path/to/store/data"));
CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration()
    .name("myCache")
    .maxBytesLocalHeap(16, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES) //размер кэша
    .maxBytesLocalOffHeap(256, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES)
    .persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP)); //стратегия персистентности

cacheManagerConfig.addCache(cacheConfig);

CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(cacheManagerConfig);
Ehcache cache = cacheManager.getEhcache("myCache");

//пихаем данные в кэш
cache.put(new Element("1","Hello"));
cache.put(new Element("2","World"));
```